# Better way to do this via pure javascript

Tags: javascript, string, url

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("=38805") > -1
  || window.location.href.indexOf("=38807") > -1
  || window.location.href.indexOf("=38816") > -1
  || window.location.href.indexOf("=38815") > -1
  || window.location.href.indexOf("=38814") > -1
  || window.location.href.indexOf("=38813") > -1
  || window.location.href.indexOf("=38811") > -1

  ){

    do something

  }
```

Basically, I am using a separate css for the pages that contain these strings. I might over 50 pages. Wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this. Put them into an array?

Comment: What if your URL contains `=3880512345`?

Comment: Why don't you extract the number, try to parse it to int and then evaluate its value?

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: This is for applying css based on url parameters

Comment: Maybe you could put values in array, or, maybe, array of objects, with key:value pairs (number:related css), and, inside loop, check if url contains key?

Comment: Probably simpler in back end to add a class to the body. Then have css rules based on body class. Also css wouldn't have to wait for javascript to load

Comment: Please [edit] your question title: it should describe what "this" is (so readers get an idea what the question is about without having to open it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JS `some` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), is exactly for stuff like that:

```
let options = ["=38805","=38807","=38816"]; //...and the others
let link = window.location.href;

if( options.some( option => link.includes(option))){
    console.log('yay! =)');
}
```

You're actually going through your array of options, and asking a question about each of the elements  in the array : "Are you present at my URL?".

Then, the `some` method will return true (and in this case- active the `if` statment ) only if one or more elements in the `options` array is answering `true` to your `includes` question.

---

And by the way- 
JS have another method that cover a similar set of mind. [the `every` metohd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

This method, as you can understand by its name, will return true only if **all the elements** in the array is answering `true` to your question.

Comment: I like this solution but keep in mind that String.prototype.includes() is not supported by IE. Use link.indexOf(option) > -1 if browser compatibility is important.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this to clean it up a bit:

```
const ids = [38805, 38807, 38811, 38813, 38814, 38815, 38816];

let windowHrefHasId = false;
for (let id of ids) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('=' + id.toString()) > -1) {
        windowHrefHasId = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (windowHrefHasId) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I need d=38805 in the id

Comment: Then if (window.location.href.indexOf('=' + id.toString()) > -1) becomes if (window.location.href.indexOf('d=' + id.toString()) > -1)